# Build Android project on Eclipse with Ant

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse, ant

Anybody knows about this kind of build failure on build.xml ?

build.xml is genereated automatically by Eclipse.

BUILD FAILED
E:\EclipseWorkspace\Launcher3\build.xml:48: Class not found: javac1.8

build.xml:48 is as following.

```
    <javac debug="true" debuglevel="${debuglevel}" destdir="bin/classes" includeantruntime="false" source="${source}" target="${target}">
```

Answer (score 0):

do you have a correctly installed and CONFIGURED jdk?

The message doesn't look so, as the compiler (`javac`) could not be found